# Group by month or 0 if not results?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT MONTH(date_added), COUNT(*)
FROM invite
WHERE YEAR(date_added) = 2013
GROUP BY MONTH(date_added)
```

And it works perfectly fine, but my problem is if there are no results for a month it doesn't output the month, I need it to say 0 instead.

I don't want to create a table with all 12 month values. And I don't want to run 12 queries, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to "create a table with 12 month values".  You can just do it in the query:

```
SELECT m.mon, COUNT(i.date_added)
FROM (select 1 as mon union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
      select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
     ) m left outer join
     invite i
     on m.mon = i.month(date_added) and year(date_added) = 2013
GROUP BY m.mon;
```

Comment: @Steven . . . I rolled back the changes for two reasons.  First, `coalesce()` is not needed with `count(<col>)`.  The `count()` will return `0`, not `NULL`.  Second, creating a subquery adds additional overhead in MySQL, so it is better to do the logic in the `on` clause.  The problem was the `where` clause, which I removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheesy way to do it:

```
create table months (int monthnum);
```

Insert the numbers 1 through 12 into months, so it's just a table with 1 column and 12 rows.

```
select monthnum, coalesce(ct, 0) from months left join (
   select month(date_added) Mon, count(*) ct from invite
   where year(date_added)=2013 group by Mon)
   on monthnum = Mon
```

Coalesce gives you a zero instead of a null if the month is missing.